Helm: errors using `default` with range and nested keys
I'm building a helm chart that can deploy one or more cronjobs.  I'd like for the jobs to be able to use some basic defaults unless otherwise specified by the devs using a custom values file.
My chart uses range for the entire file so that it can deploy multiple cronjobs, if defined, and uses with to be able to access the "root" values as the defaults.
Basic key-value pairs work just fine using the default function like below:
concurrencyPolicy: {{ default .Values.concurrencyPolicy $job.concurrencyPolicy }}
However, I'm running into problems with nested values:
image:
  repository: {{ default .Values.image.repository $job.image.repository }}

# I get a "nil pointer evaluating $job.image.repository", as if it can't access sub-keys.

Any help would be appreciated.

It would be helpful if you could share the whole templates and values files - or at least enough code for us to reproduce the issue.

Does image: exist in the per-job values?

Not sure if it is the "right" way to do this, but we ended up putting all our default values under the "global" section of the values file, and then added a "cronjobs" entry that defaults with a single item in the list.  The template then loops through the "cronjobs" list, and for each item, if a particular property isn't defined for that item, it defaults to the global value.  In english pseudo-code:
For each cronjob defined, if "image.repository" isn't defined, use the value for "global.image.repository".
I'vd put in code excerpts, but i'd reach my character limit

This approach allowed our Dev teams to use the chart straight up with a single cronjob item with all defaults.  But, they could also add on their own values file that could define X-amount of cronjobs, and customize any config as needed(schedule, secrets, env vars, etc.)
